# replacing dataframe using pool from multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to replace rows of a dataframe using pool from multiprocessing.

When I run the following code, multiprocessing seems to keep the output somewhere but does not replace new_df as I expected. Is there any way that I correct this?

```
df = pd.read_excel("data.xlsx")
size = (len(df)*3, len(df.iloc[0]))
new_df = np.zeros(size)
new_df = pd.DataFrame(new_df)
i = range(len(df))

def work(j):    
    new_df.iloc[j*3,:] = np.array(df.iloc[j,:])


cpuCount = multiprocessing.cpu_count()    
if __name__ == "__main__":

    pool = Pool(processes=cpuCount)
    pool.map(work, i)
    pool.close()

new_df.to_csv("result.csv")
```

Comment: Is there a reason your using multiprocessing to do this? Doesn't strike me as a problem that would need to be solved in this way. Also, please proved some sample data as a copy an paste-able. Your problem cannot be reproduced with `pd.read_excel()`

Comment: use dask, that's more suited for this sort of thing.

Comment: @djk47463 it's times series data with daily observations for more than ten years, so it took a lot of time if I did not use multiprocessing. Also, the code that I posted is just an example, so any kind of dataframe would be fine. So, for df = pd.DataFrame(np.ones((10, 10)))

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Thanks, I'll try that